# Submit button in my jsp file don't work

Tags: forms

This is the jsp file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>FIKT | Sign Up</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/icon.ico">
  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonTeacher").click(function(){
        $(".teacher").css("display", "block");

        $(".signUp").css("display", "inline");
        $(".student").hide();
    });

    $("#buttonStudent").click(function(){
        $(".student").css("display", "block");
        $(".signUp").css("display", "inline");

        $(".teacher").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Login.jsp">FIKT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="About.jsp">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="Login.jsp">SIGN IN</a></li>
        <li><a href="Register.jsp">SIGN UP</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.jsp">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" id="signInDiv">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Hello_World/RegisterServlet" method="get">
           <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Please choose:</h4><br>
      <div class="panel-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-lg" id="buttonTeacher">Teacher</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg" id="buttonStudent">Student</button>
      </div>      
      </div>
    <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first">First:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name" required>
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="last">Last:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="idTeacher">Teacher ID:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teacherId" name="teacherId" placeholder="Enter your teacher ID" required>
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="pass">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">          
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
      </div>
    </div>





    <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first">First:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name" >
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="last">Last:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="idStudent">Student index:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teacherId" name="studentId" placeholder="Enter your index" >
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="pass">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">          
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" >
      </div>
    </div>



        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-lg signUp" type="submit" style="display:none;">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>




<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <a href="#myPage" title="To Top">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="http://www.kddesign.comlu.com" title="Visit KDdesign">&copy KDdesign All rights reserved 2016</a></p> 
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and java servlet that handles it :

```
package gui;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Helloworld
 */
@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegisterServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String teacherId = request.getParameter("teacherId");
        String studentId = request.getParameter("studentId");

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");   
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");       

        DbConnector db = new DbConnector();
        db.Connect();
        System.out.println(firstName+" "+lastName+" "+teacherId);

        System.out.println(studentId);

        if (firstName !=null && password !=null && !db.validateUser(firstName, password)){
            if (teacherId!=null){
                System.out.println("teachers");
                db.addUser(teacherId, firstName, lastName, password, email,"teacher");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("studenti");
                db.addUser(studentId, firstName, lastName, password, email,"student");
            }
                request.setAttribute("user", firstName);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Success.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else 
            System.out.print("FAILED!");


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

When Student div is selected and click on Sign up the button dont run the servlet RegisterServlet.Why my button only submits for Teacher div instead for both..?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say with any certainty that my answer is correct without seeing the form data in your GET request, but I suspect that the student values are not being read in favour of the teacher values — even if they're null/empty — because you have both the teacher and student `input` fields in a single `form` with the same `name` attributes on those `input` fields. This means that `firstName` and `lastName` are submitted twice, and it will look something like this when a student tries to submit the form:

```
firstName :         [Teacher]
firstName : "John"  [Student]
lastName  :         [Teacher]
lastName  : "Doe"   [Student]
```

The teacher values may be used because they appear first, but if you're filling out the form for a student they will be empty so it won't work.

At best, both values will be pushed into an array for the same property by your server-side code and then the behaviour will already be unexpected. Maybe something like `firstName = ["","John"]` but honestly I'm not sure how JSP would handle it as I have not developed with JSP, coming from a Perl background. As I said it, JSP might just take the first value for the property it finds in the form data.

This goes for all the duplicated `name` attributes, i.e. password, email etc.

To avoid this issue, separate the teacher and student `input` elements into two separate `form` elements, so only one set of values for `firstName` and `lastName` is submitted to the server when someone tries to register/login, not both sets, if that makes sense. The `id` attributes for the input elements should also be unique, so where your `input` elements might currently share the same `id="firstName"` it should be `id="teacherFirstName"` and `id="studentFirstName"` to prevent parsing/HTML validity issues.

Additionally, I can see that you're using the *HTML4 Transitional* DOCTYPE. Your `input` fields include the `required` and `placeholder` attributes which are HTML5 features, and also your `body` element has `data-` attributes which are also a HTML5 feature. I recommend using the *HTML5* DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) or consider revising the code to remove HTML5 features to prevent parsing errors for whatever browsers you are targeting. It would probably be better to use the HTML5 DOCTYPE because Bootstrap does a lot of `data-` attribute manipulation.

I can also see that you specify two differing character sets: first `ISO-8859-1` via declared in JSP and `meta http-equiv` tag, and then `UTF-8` via `meta charset="utf-8"`. It would probably be best not to supply both and to use whichever charset you need. The `meta http-equiv` tag should also be included within your `<head>` element or HTML parsers may simply ignore it.

You also need to add one more `</div>` to close `<div class="panel-body">` and `&copy` should be `&copy;` to prevent possible parser problems.

See the snippet below for the HTML generated by your JSP with my suggested amends (if UTF-8 is fine)

**JSP preamble:**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

**HTML output:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>FIKT | Sign Up</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/icon.ico">
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonTeacher").click(function(){
        $(".teacher").css("display", "block");
        $(".student").hide();
    });

    $("#buttonStudent").click(function(){
        $(".student").css("display", "block");
        $(".teacher").hide();
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Login.jsp">FIKT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="About.jsp">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="Login.jsp">SIGN IN</a></li>
        <li><a href="Register.jsp">SIGN UP</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.jsp">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" id="signInDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          
            <div class="form-group">
              <h4>Please choose:</h4><br>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg" id="buttonTeacher">Teacher</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg" id="buttonStudent">Student</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          
          <form class="form-horizontal teacher" role="form" action="/Hello_World/RegisterServlet" method="get">
            <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first">First:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name" required>
              </div>
               <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="last">Last:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="idTeacher">Teacher ID:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teacherId" name="teacherId" placeholder="Enter your teacher ID" required>
              </div>
               <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="pass">Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group teacher" style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">E-mail:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg teacherSignUp" type="submit" style="display:none;">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          
          <form class="form-horizontal student" role="form" action="/Hello_World/RegisterServlet" method="get">
            <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first">First:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentFirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name" >
              </div>
               <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="last">Last:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentLastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="idStudent">Student index:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentId" name="id" placeholder="Enter your index" >
              </div>
               <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="pass">Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="studentPassword" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group student"  style="display:none;">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">E-mail:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="studentEmail" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" >
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg studentSignUp" type="submit" style="display:none;">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <a href="#myPage" title="To Top">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </a>
  <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="http://www.kddesign.comlu.com" title="Visit KDdesign">&copy; KDdesign All rights reserved 2016</a></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

([**Code diff**](http://www.mergely.com/o0JvqThs/))